# open as sbt project takes forever

Tags: java, macos, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I've installed in Intellij Ultimate 2019.3 the Scala and SBT executor plugins.
In the import as window I do not see the SBT as an import as option.
I am opening the build.sbt file as a sbt project.
The sbt dump seems to work with lots of downloads showing.
Then it seems to just pause. The sbt import is not showing any progress at all.
The indexing process is waiting for the sbt import.
Can you suggest any way to improve this?
The JDK is 8 (this is what we use alongside Scala 12 and SBT 1.2 or 1.3).

Answer (score 0):

i've noticed this also but with JDK 13, sbt 1.3.9, and scala 2.13.1.  however, it has only been on a somewhat memory constrained laptop.  did we cross a threshold somewhere?